# Can we deconstruct arbitrary data constructors?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching

In Haskell, or any other programming language supporting pattern matching, can we achieve the following:

Given a data constructor e.g. `Left :: a -> Either a b` I can extract its argument with

```
let f (Left x) = [x]
```

Is there any way to achieve the same thing for any data constructor, something like an operator (`*`) to lift `Left x` to `Apply (λa.Left a) [x]` or `BinTree x y` to `Apply (λa,b.BinTree a b) [x,y]`, so we could do

```
let extract x = case *x of Apply _ xs -> xs
```

Comment: Those are not _type_ constructors, they are _value_ constructors, or simply "constructors". Type constructors are `Maybe, Either, IO, State, ...` which are things of kind `*->*->....->*`.

Comment: I think that's an answer, @kosmikus. And chi has a point: `Left` is a value constructor, not a type.

Comment: @kosmikus Isn't syb deprecated?

Comment: @arrowd "Deprecated" sounds harsh. I personally think there are better options. But it works, is still widely used, and as far as I know, it's perfectly well maintained.

Answer (score 3):

Not directly, primarily because the arguments of constructors will generally be of different types.

You can achieve similar things using various generic programming libraries. For example `gfoldl`, `gmapT`, `gmapQ` from [syb](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb) let you operate on subterms uniformly, and in [generics-sop](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop), you can represent the arguments of a constructor as a heterogeneous list.